# how can I generate a Diffie-Hellman public key and shared secret key from a prime and peer key that is a sequence of 128 bytes?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
unsigned char *prime;
unsigned char *keyPeer;
unsigned char *generator = [self.client readBytesWithLength:2];

unsigned char *keyLengthRaw = [self.client readBytesWithLength:2];
int keyLength = keyLengthRaw[0]*256+keyLengthRaw[1];

prime = [self.client readBytesWithLength:keyLength];
keyPeer = [self.client readBytesWithLength:keyLength];

NSLog(@"key length %d",keyLength);
NSLog(@"---generator: %d", (int) generator[0]*256+generator[1]);
NSLog(@"---prime:");
NSLog([NSString stringWithCString:prime encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"---peerkey:");
NSLog([NSString stringWithCString:keyPeer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

what do i have to do after this point to generate the dh public key and shared secret key?

Comment: It would be far more effective to generate an RSA key.  Diffie-Hellman is a rather... Outdated cryptographic avenue.

Comment: Also, DH keys are 48 bytes...

Comment: I'm creating a client that needs authenticate using DH. Not really my call. Also, the key they gave me was 128 bytes, but just using 49 as generic example.